# Ant trouble with sshexec

Tags: xml, ant, build.xml

I have some ant script and here is trouble, when I run this part of my script:

```
<sshexec host="${deploy.system.hostname}" port="**" trust="true"
                username="*********"
                password="**********"
        commandResource="CommandsDeploy.txt"/>
```

I received this cmd message:

```
[sshexec] cmd : C:
[sshexec] cmd : DIR
[sshexec]
[sshexec]  Directory of U:\
[sshexec]
[sshexec] 11/13/2013  01:25 PM    <DIR>          .
[sshexec] 11/13/2013  01:25 PM    <DIR>          ..
[sshexec] 11/19/2013  05:46 PM    <DIR>          WINDOWS
```

My CommandsDeploy.txt looks like that:

```
c:
DIR
```

Script executing on Windows Server 2008R2 trough ssh connection, and if I do this commands by manual in console, they works. What can I do with it ?

Comment: Looks to me like it's working.... The sshexec command is printing out the windows directory listing.

Comment: It is listing u:\ not c:\. So it is not working...

Comment: What kind of SSH server are you using?